# Programmatically change page background in Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, background-image

I'm new to Windows 8 development and I'm stuck on the this question. Basically, I have main page and I want change its background image every time when application is started. Please help !!!!

Comment: you can use css `background` attribute if it is html based windows store app

Comment: I use XAML and C#, I'm new to C#, I tried this.Frame ((Frame) this.Content).Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/GameBG/bg1_1366x768.jpg")) }; but it does not work and I got NullPointerException :(. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Uri` in your `ViewModel`, and have your `Background`'s `ImageBrush` bind to this `Uri`. Then, on app startup, have your app just change the `Uri` to whatever new image you want, using whatever logic you want.

Also, when using `ImageSource` as you mentioned in the comments, you should be using `SetSource`.